# Unpredictable stop program woking with list and vectors

Tags: c++, list, vector, runtime-error, adjacency-list

the problem is documented in the code, look at him. I try to push_back an edge but it is not inserted. Maybe I should initialize even the lists but I've done in the constructor and nothing changes

Here is the function where I try to add the edge to teh adjacency list:

```
    void Graph::addEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2){
        if(!adjacent(vertex1, vertex2))  // if there isn't yet a Edge
            adjacency_list[vertex1].push_back(Edge(vertex2, 1));  // add this edge without weight
            std::cout << Edge(vertex2, 1) << std::endl;  // THE OBJECT EDJE IS PROPERLY CREATED
            std::cout << adjacency_list[vertex1].size() << std::endl;  // THE SIZE IS EVERYTIME 0
            printlist(adjacency_list[vertex1]);  // THIS FUNCTION PRINTS JUST end, IN THE LIST THERE IS NOTHING
    }
```

And here the constructor of graph, where there is the adjacency list variable and his initialization

```
    class Graph{
    public:
            //Graph constructor that takes as parameter the number of vertices in the Graph
            Graph(int NumberOfVertices):vertices(NumberOfVertices),             
                                        edges(0),
                                        adjacency_list(NumberOfVertices){
                                                     for(int x = 0; x < numberOfVertices; x++) adjacency_list[x] = std::list<Edge>();
                                                 };
            ~Graph() { adjacency_list.clear(); }
            int V() const { return vertices; }
            int E() const { return edges; }
            Edge returnEdge(std::list<Edge> list, const int vertex2);
            bool adjacent (int vertex1, int vertex2);
            std::list<Edge> neighbors(int vertex1) const;
            void addEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2);
            Edge *deleteFromList(Edge *list, const int vertex2);
            void deleteEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2);
            int getEdgeWeight(int vertex1, int vertex2);
            void setEdgeWeight(int vertex1, int vertex2, int weight);
            int incrementEdges() { edges++; }  //increment by 1 the number of edges

    private: int vertices,                                        //number of vertices
                 edges;                                           //number of edges
            std::vector<std::list<Edge> > adjacency_list;  //adjacency_list: every element of index x the vector is a list of edges from x
};
```

I'm wondering if I should initialize every lists in the `adjacency_list` vector but I don't know how to do that. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: It might be an invalid index issue. Try using `adjacency_list.at(vertex1)` in your code to see if an error is raised. As a side note, the code in your constructor (the `for` loop) is useless (the creation of empty lists is implicit once you typed `adjacency_list(NumberOfVertices)`).

Comment: if I use at the program continue till the end, but the function stops at that line, the output debug aren't shows

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible out-of-range problem in the line `adjacency_list[vertex1].push_back(Edge(vertex2, 1));` Namely `operator[]` does not signal if the requested index is out of range. To resolve this issue you can

1. check the maximum index for `adjacency_list` vector by `adjacency_list.max_size()` method and then resize the vector, if necessary, using `adjacency_list.resize()` or
2. use `adjacency_list.at()` to index the vector but check for the `out-of-range` exception.

For the performance reason it would be the most convenient to build the large enough vector at the beginning.

Yet another way could be to use `map<list<Edge> >` (or unordered_map) instead of `vector`.

Comment: if I use at the program continue till the end, but the function stops at that line, the output debug aren't shown